# Unable to set cache capacity in cassandra 1.1

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to enable the row caching for some of the CFs in Cassandra 1.1.

```
UPDATE COLUMN FAMILY Users WITH rows_cached=2000 AND row_cache_provider='SerializingCacheProvider';
```

If I run above command in CLI then it gives error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient$ColumnFamilyArgument.ROWS_CACHED
```

Then I tried another approach of nodetool setcachecapacity
    nodetool -h cssa01-04 setcachecapacity keyspace1 Users 200000 2000

It gives an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.setCapacity(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:291)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cache.ConcurrentLinkedHashCache.setCapacity(ConcurrentLinkedHashCache.java:87)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cache.InstrumentingCache.updateCapacity(InstrumentingCache.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cache.InstrumentingCache.setCapacity(InstrumentingCache.java:84)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CacheService.setKeyCacheCapacityInMB(CacheService.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:93)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:27)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeSetter(MBeanIntrospector.java:238)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.setAttribute(PerInterface.java:84)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.setAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:240)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.setAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:762)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.setAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:699)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1450)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1265)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1360)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.setAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:683)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any idea how to fix this one?

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassandra 1.1 you no longer need to set cache capacity on individual columnfamilies.  Instead, just set caching=rows_only, as well as a total cache size in cassandra.yaml.

See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/caching-in-cassandra-1-1 for more details.

Comment: Thanks Jonethan for reply.Question in my mind.If user want to enable row cache for hot CFs which have very small data.If we enable global row cache then data from other CFs will be there in memory results in weared results.Am I right? ... If yes what should be done in that case?

Comment: To clarify how to update the CF via CQL: ALTER TABLE Users WITH caching='rows_only';

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with Cassandra's code, but CLHM's precondition is that capacity is cannot be negative. HTH

```
  /**
   * Sets the maximum weighted capacity of the map and eagerly evicts entries
   * until it shrinks to the appropriate size.
   *
   * @param capacity the maximum weighted capacity of the map
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the capacity is negative
   */
  public void setCapacity(long capacity) {
    if (capacity < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have described How to enable caching for Cassandra-1.1 here : [Caching in Cassandra-1.1](http://www.shareitexploreit.blogspot.in/2012/05/caching-in-cassandra-11.html)